# Publishing to Facebook Wall?

Tags: facebook

Using the Facebook PHP SDK, what steps do I need to take to allow a user to post to their Facebook wall from another website?

For example:

- User logs in to external website
- User creates a post
- User clicks 'Push to Facebook' before submitting
- Summarized post appears on Facebook wall (Soandso just posted to mysite.com/entry/page! something like that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you have two options available:

- Use the [feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/). This option doesn't let you automatically publish to Facebook (requires user intervention) but it does let you populate the feed story and doesn't require an install. (The feed dialog isn't really related to the PHP SDK, but it's still an option.)
- Use a [POST](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) to the user's `/feed`. (Scroll down to publishing.) This method will require an install and [additional permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions), but should let you post without user intervention and should still let you alter the content however you want. You can even ask for `offline_access` and post it later if you want. This will also let you populate the `message` parameter, or the status of the post, something which Facebook [recently deprecated in the dialogs](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/510/).

Comment: Does that mean you can't make it a generic update? I want to post about activity, but not necessarily what the content is.

Comment: It's up to you what the post contains, but the content of the post is immaterial to Facebook. Unless you're using native Facebook functionality (like `<fb:like>`, which doesn't allow you to change the sentence structure but does give you the free one-line story), you're bound to these options.